# Why my scss/sass is not working anymore suddenly?

Tags: html, css, json, sass

I just have some of problem here at my scss files at any parts of my folder wherein it doesn't work anymore and I don't understand why..I tried to research it but I couldn't find the same error that I have?

Its on my react or any normal html in my react I already install it my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-messages",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^4.4.5",
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here in the image as you see its not working anymore..
I didn't touch anything that changes on my terminal or does the SCSS changes???
[image]

Here is my bottom right corner thing
[image]

Comment: Is your language mode correct? Look in the bottom-right corner of VScode. Do you see SCSS there?

Comment: yes it is..every part of my projects with scss suddenly becomes like that...It's like happen tomorrow before I notice now.

Comment: @humanbean look at my update at the thing you say in image

Comment: Your file info says that this is `JS React` Somehow you set your VSCode to interpret SCSS files as JS Files. Change this setting then it should work again.

Comment: where can I find that setting? I'm so lost lol.

Comment: please comment back @cloned so I can tell which was my problem in settings

Comment: You just click where it says `JavaScript React` in the bottom part. Then you can edit the settings for file associations.

Answer (score -4):

1. Maybe the location of CSS file is changed.
2. Invalid CSS format.
3. Try a different browser.